# Get reference of SKLabelNode from SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to get a reference to `SKLabelNode`. Any ideas?

I tried doing like this:

```
 let score = 10
 let label = SKLabelNode(fileNamed: "ScoreLabel")
 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
 label.text = score
}
```

The text does not change to 10, it stays on 0 as default on `SKScene`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference it like so:

```
let label = childNode(named: "ScoreLabel")
```

That easy :)

edit:

`let label = SKLabelNode(fileNamed: "ScoreLabel")` creates a new label, it does not grab the label on your scene

`let label = childNode(named: "ScoreLabel")` grabs the label named "ScoreLabel" that is on your scene.  Note, it must be an immediate child to your scene, it cannot be a grand child of any kind.

Comment: Hi, can you explain, what does fileNamed means?

Comment: Don't really know... never used it

Comment: `FileNamed` is usually used with `SKSpriteNode` to create a sprite from an image file.

Comment: when you define your `score` property, if you use a property observer (`didSet`) then you can get the label;'s text to update automatically whenever `score` changes.